# Uploading File to Server from Xamarin CrossMedia Plugin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a xamarin forms based cross platform mobile application, I am new to this technology, hontestly.

I am using this plgin to to upload files to the server

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FileUploaderPlugin

but it does not seems to work at all, at server I am not getting any POST value at all.

I have tried xamarin community forum, but it didn't help too.

I suppose there could be problem like this

1. Path issue
   but I have printed path on screen and its correct
2. URL being hit
   I have verfied that as well by performing some other action on server, URL is being hit too, it performed the other action but did not get any POST

Here is my C# code

```
string url = "http://example.com/file_upload.php";

Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters.Add("fileName", "Kamran");

// filePath returns correct value I have verified that
FilePathItem fpi = new FilePathItem("file", filePath);

Dictionary<string, string> header = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            header.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

await CrossFileUploader.Current.UploadFileAsync(url,fpi,header, parameters, null);
```

Here is my Server side code

```
<?php 
$n = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $n;
$senderName = $_POST['fileName'];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. : " .$n.", sender: " . $senderName;
    }
?>
```

I do not see any POSTED vars, I trield saving all posted vars as JSON string as well, but nothing is coming.

Comment: You can implement the event `FileUploadCompleted`  and `FileUploadError` to check if there is some error message .

Comment: I have that already and there is no error message, there is no error actually sending http request, its not carrying POSTED values, this is the problem

Comment: Did you add user permission?

Comment: Yes I have added directory permission on server, as well as on app for user level, I am getting file correctly I have access to file. Is this permissions you are talking about?

Comment: You can create a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: you can download code from here, only use "Pick Photo" http://creativerays.com/ju/App7.zip

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT let me know when you get it running

Comment: OK , I will check it, don't forget to remove your personal info from the sample ,such as password and account ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198919/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-creative).

Answer (score 2):

I know it might seems stupid, but I am just posting the answer so, someone might not forget this simple thing and add it into checklist of while debugging.

The simple issue was http and https, web server URL must be with "https" not http, maybe there are ways to work with http too, but in situation it was not allowing without "https" there was nothing wrong with rest of the code at all.